# 1004 error using combox selections to update a dataset

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a userform with which the user can use command buttons to scroll through the data, some of which is displayed in text boxes.
I have a 2 comboboxes, one dependent on the other, which use case statements. I want to use these combobox selections to update the original data, but I keep getting error 1004.

I've set up `CommandButton3_Click()`, which I want the user to press once they have made a selection using the comboboxes. Ideally, I'd also like the selections from the combobox to overwrite the values displayed in textbox 1 and 3. That's a nice to have though.

The code I'm having a problem with is below and `Me.ComboxCat2Name` and `Me.ComboxCat3Name` are the `comboxbox` selections:

```
Worksheets("CurrentMonth").Range(Cells(Currentrow, 31)) = Me.ComboBoxCat2Name
Worksheets("CurrentMonth").Range(Cells(Currentrow, 33)) = Me.ComboBoxCat3Name
```

My full code for my userform is below:

```
Option Explicit


Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Currentrow As Long


Private Sub ComboBoxCat2Name_Change()

'Clears 2nd ComboBox each time the 1st is picked so no previous selection   residual is left
Me.ComboBoxCat3Name = ""
'Contingent ComboBoxes that pull values from lots of named ranges as below
Select Case Me.ComboBoxCat2Name
    Case "B2C"
        Me.ComboBoxCat3Name.RowSource = "B2C"
    Case "B2B"
        Me.ComboBoxCat3Name.RowSource = "B2B"
    Case "Games Dev"
        Me.ComboBoxCat3Name.RowSource = "GamesDev"
    Case "SimGam"
        Me.ComboBoxCat3Name.RowSource = "SimGam"
    Case "RGS"
        Me.ComboBoxCat3Name.RowSource = "RGS"
    Case "RMG"
        Me.ComboBoxCat3Name.RowSource = "RMG"
    Case "IT"
        Me.ComboBoxCat3Name.RowSource = "IT"
    Case "Head Office"
        Me.ComboBoxCat3Name.RowSource = "HeadOffice"
    Case "System Sales"
        Me.ComboBoxCat3Name.RowSource = "SystemSales"

End Select

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Worksheets("CurrentMonth").Range(Cells(Currentrow, 31)) = Me.ComboBoxCat2Name
Worksheets("CurrentMonth").Range(Cells(Currentrow, 33)) = Me.ComboBoxCat3Name

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Worksheets("CurrentMonth").Select
Currentrow = 2
TextBox1.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 31).Text
TextBox2.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 30).Text
TextBox3.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 33).Text
TextBox4.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 32).Text
TextBox5.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 9).Text
TextBox6.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 67).Text
TextBox11.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 28).Text
TextBox12.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 68).Text
TextBox13.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 29).Text

Me.ComboBoxCat2Name = ""
Me.ComboBoxCat3Name = ""

End Sub

Private Sub CommandNext_Click()

Lastrow = Worksheets("CurrentMonth").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Currentrow = Currentrow + 1
If Currentrow = Lastrow + 1 Then
MsgBox ("You have reached the last record in this set of data")
Currentrow = Lastrow
End If
TextBox1.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 31).Text
TextBox2.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 30).Text
TextBox3.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 33).Text
TextBox4.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 32).Text
TextBox5.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 9).Text
TextBox6.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 67).Text
TextBox11.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 28).Text
TextBox12.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 68).Text
TextBox13.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 29).Text

End Sub

Private Sub CommandPrevious_Click()

Currentrow = Currentrow - 1
If Currentrow > 1 Then
TextBox1.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 31).Text
TextBox2.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 30).Text
TextBox3.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 33).Text
TextBox4.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 32).Text
TextBox5.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 9).Text
TextBox6.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 67).Text
TextBox11.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 28).Text
TextBox12.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 68).Text
TextBox13.Text = Cells(Currentrow, 29).Text
ElseIf Currentrow = 1 Then
MsgBox ("This is the first row")
Currentrow = Currentrow + 1
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You should probably have some validation to make sure the user has actually selected a value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing those two lines with this:

```
Worksheets("CurrentMonth").Cells(Currentrow, 31).Value = Me.ComboBoxCat2Name.Value
Worksheets("CurrentMonth").Cells(Currentrow, 33).Value = Me.ComboBoxCat3Name.Value
```

Comment: Many thanks - you'll never know how many things I'd tried. Simple when you know how :-)